# How can I make a clothes rack from this pipe?

Tags: pipe, closet

I found this piping in the shape of :

[image: Piping]

I want to turn it into a clothes rack since I have NO closet space.

I want it to be up right so the bottom pipe needs to be mounted to something to stabilize it.

It is one piece of pipe so the corners there are no connections, it is just bent at the corners. The beginning and end connect sort of like a male/female type connection but it is in one of the straight areas of the pipe.

Suggestions on how to do so...(simply, as I have only a few tools: a drill, hammer, and wrenches.)?

Comment: How big is your closet, what are you trying to do, how big is the pipe?  What is currently in your closet?

Comment: Actually I don't have a closet so I am using a small bedroom as my dressing area/closet.  Small bedroom, big closet.  The pipe dimensions are around 3.5' by 5'.  The pipe itself I am guessing is about 1.5" in diameter.

Comment: Some more details would help.  Do you want it 3.5 ft wide and 5 ft tall, or 5 ft wide by 3.5 ft tall?  What tools do you have?  How are the corners of this pipe held together right now?

Comment: I want it 5ft wide by 3.5 ft tall.  Of course I am thinking the height would be raised somewhat by whatever base is used.  I have a drill, hammer, and wrenches.  It is one piece of pipe so the corners there are no connections, it is just bent at the corners.  The beginning and end connect sort of like a male/female type connection but it is in one of the straight areas of the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea. Hang it from the ceiling with chain. You can then use both the top and bottom bar to hang clothes. You'll need a couple of heavy hooks to screw into the ceiling joist, some attractive chain, and a clasp to connect the chain over the pipe. You can find all of this at Lowes, Home Depot, or a hardware store. Tell them what you're doing and they'll probably be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to make this into a clothing rack is to add a piece of wood as a base or "foot".

You can probably remove one side of the rectangle to turn it into an upside-down "U" shape.  Connect the sides to a wood base using pipe flanges.

If this is put together with threaded plumbing pipe, you can simply buy flanges to match at the hardware store and screw them onto the ends of the pipes.

[image: pipe flange]

If you cannot disconnect one side or determine how to add pipe flanges, then you could hold it on to a wooden base using pipe clamps.  Add two sides to the base, and clamp the pipes both to the bottom base as well as the sides.

Something like this:

[image: pipe base]

[image: pipe clamp]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand both of those.  Really like the first idea, but I would have to get someone to remove one of those sides for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: Here's another idea: make the sides very tall, like perhaps 4 feet.  Use pipe clamps to hold the pipe rack to the upper part of the two sides (say, 2 or 3 clamps per side), so the bottom pipe is for example 30 inches above the floor, and the top pipe is 3.5 feet above that.  Then you will have *two* rails for hanging things on, one above the other.